# How can we compute the skewness coefficient of the sample variance given by $E(\frac{[S^2-E(S^2)]^3}{[Var(S^2)]^{3/2}})$ in terms of the moments of X?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value, variance

I have been trying to compute the skewness coefficient of the sample variance given by $E(\frac{[S^2-E(S^2)]^3}{[Var(S^2)]^{3/2}})$. I have used $E(S^2)=\sigma^2$ and I have ended up with $\frac{E(S^6)-3\sigma^2Var(S^2)-\sigma^6}{[Var(S^2)]^{3/2}}$ where $Var(S^2)= \frac{1}{n} [E(X-\mu)^4-(\frac{n-3}{n-1})\sigma^4]$. How do we proceed? How can $E(S^6)$ be computed? Can my result be simplified so as to be expressed in terms of just $\mu$, $\sigma$, n and $E(X-\mu)^4$? I would like the result to be more general and not depending on the sample variance which is different each time. So I thought of using $S^2=\frac{\Sigma(x_i-\bar{x})^2}{n-1}$ but then I got many terms one of which was $E[(\Sigma x_i^2)^6]$. How can this be expressed in terms of the moments of X? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: $E(S^6)$ will need to be involved somewhere no matter what. It depends on $S$ itself and cannot be computed from $\sigma$, $\mu$, and $n$. It's not clear what sort of answer you'd find helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will edit my post to make it clearer.

Comment: The answer cannot be expressed in terms of only $\mu, \sigma, n$. It will depend on higher moments of $X$. Perhaps your question is: how does one express the skewness of the sample variance in terms of the moments of $X$?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I was just correcting it,because I thought, too, it was not possible to exclude the term $E(X-\mu)^4$, but you were a little bit quicker since it took me a while until I sign in.